# Creating an object

Tags: java, object

```
Box buttonBox = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);  
Name1 name2 = new Name1();
```

there are two Name1s

```
checkboxList = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();  
name2 = new Name1();
```

there is only one Name1

It works, but why?

Comment: having slightly clearer names for your types and your variable names would probably help a lot.

Comment: yeah its easy to get confused with those names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first time, the `Name1 name2` declares a variable of type `Name1` called `name2`, then it is immediately assigned to `new Name1()`. The second time, the variable already exists; you're just reassigning it.

Some people like to use:

```
Name1 name2;
name2 = new Name1();
```

instead of the equivalent:

```
Name1 name2 = new Name1();
```

but I find the second one much easier to read.

I suggest you go through the [Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/), especially [Getting Started](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) and [Learning the Java Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/index.html). They cover all sorts of beginner questions like this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Name1 name2 = new Name1();
```

In this line, you are doing two things:

1. declare a variable named `name2` of type `Name1`
2. create an object by calling the no-argument constructor of the class `Name1` and assign a reference to the newly-create object to the variable `name2`

You can also separate the steps:

```
Name1 name2;
name2 = new Name1();
```

In your second piece of code, you are only doing step 2, and *reusing* (i.e. overwriting) the already existing variable `name2`. This is possible because once declared, variables can be used (read from *and* written to) as often as you want within the same scope. The exception are `final` variables, which you can only write to once. If you do this:

```
final Name1 name2 = new Name1();
name2 = new Name1();
```

You'll get a compiler error because you're trying to the same variable a second time. This can be useful because it prevents programmer errors that occur when you reuse variables.

Answer (score 0):

As Mmyers said, you've already declared a variable of *class* Name1 named name2.

What happens when you write `X y = new X()` is three things:

1. To the left of the equals sign you're **declaring** variable y as being of type X. It hasn't been created yet and doesn't exist in memory, you're simply saying that it's going to exist.
2. To the right you **create** an instance of X using the keyword *new*. It now exists in the heap.
3. The equals sign itself **assigns** the instance created in step 2. to the variable created in step 1.

In your second line you've simply skipped step 1. and created a new instance, which you assigned to an already used variable.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the matters of syntax and formality already described, it is generally considered a best practice to not reuse variables in this way. The reason is one of state explosion; if a variable could *potentially* be in a different state at any given point in your program then you have to deal with more possibilities. Therefore it's generally better to declare and use *separate* variables marking them 'final' as posted by Michael Borgwardt.